# NullPointerException error when implementing own class java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a solitaire counting program. I already have the main program working but when I try to implement my own class I get an NullPointerException error on line 19 (whenever it reaches `c.getRank`).

Note that I first created my main program while importing a class called `CardDeck` that has all the functions I need for it to work but now I'm supposed to create my own class that does the exact same thing. (Note that I don't have access to the imported `CardDeck` class).

Here is the main code:

```
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.cardGames.Card;

public class Patiens {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double good = 0;
    double bad = 0;
    double result = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < 1000000; a++) {
        CardDeck deck = new CardDeck();
        deck.shuffle();
        double fail = 0;
        while (deck.moreCards()) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3 && deck.moreCards(); i++) {

                Card c = deck.getCard();

                if (i == 1 && c.getRank() == 1) {
                    fail++;
                }

                if (i == 2 && c.getRank() == 2) {
                    fail++;
                }

                if (i == 3 && c.getRank() == 3) {
                    fail++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (fail >= 1) {
            bad++;      
        }
        else{
            good++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Good: " + good + " Bad: " + bad);
    result = good / bad;
    System.out.println("Result= " + result);
}

}
```

What it does is count the probability that my deck will finish successfully:

It's counting 1-2-3, 1-2-3 while at the same time drawing a card. Now IF the card happens to be an ACE when it counts "1" the current deck will fail. Same goes for a card of rank 2 while the program counts "2" etc. The probability that it will finish without failing once is 0.8% .

Here is the CardDeck class I'm creating:

```
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.cardGames.Card;

import java.util.Random;

public class CardDeck {
    private Card[] cards;
    private int current;
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public CardDeck() {
        cards = new Card[52];
        for(int suit = Card.SPADES; suit <= Card.CLUBS; suit++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                cards[i * suit] = new Card(suit, i);
            }
        }
        current = 0;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Card k;
        for(int i = 1000; i > 0; i--) {
            int nbr = rand.nextInt(52);
            int nbr2 = rand.nextInt(52);
            k = cards[nbr2];
            cards[nbr2] = cards[nbr];
            cards[nbr] = k;
        }
    }

    /**
     *Checks for more cards
     */
    public boolean moreCards() {
        if(current > 51) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     *Draws the card lying on top.
     */
    public Card getCard() {
        return cards[current++];

    }
}
```

Here is the `import se.lth.cs.ptdc.cardGames.Card;` If needed, It is the class that creates the cards.

```
package se.lth.cs.ptdc.cardGames;

public class Card {
    public static final int SPADES = 1;
    public static final int HEARTS = SPADES + 1;
    public static final int DIAMONDS = SPADES + 2;
    public static final int CLUBS = SPADES + 3;

    private int suit;
    private int rank;

    public Card(int suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
}
```

(Note that I'm not supposed to change the above class)

Comment: Always include the stack trace if you asking to debug an excpetion.

Comment: put a print statement in `getCard()` method for `current` count and check in which index Card object is null

Comment: Or just learn to use the debugger, this should be really simple debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
cards[i * suit] = new Card(suit, i);
```

If you change this to:

```
cards[i + ((suit - 1) * 13)] = new Card(suit, i);
```

It will do what you expect.

Two things to consider:  firstly, arrays are **zero-based**, so your first card needs to be at index 0.  Secondly, by multiplying by the suit, you will get multiples of that number, e.g.:

- SPADES: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
- HEARTS: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ...
- DIAMONDS: 3, 6, 9, 12 ...
- CLUBS: 4, 8, 12, 16 ...

So some elements will be filled more than once (12 is filled four times), and some (particular prime numbers > 13) elements (e.g. 23) will be null.  In general, it's probably enough to represent the index with another variable, like so:

```
int cardIndex = 0;
for (int suit = Card.SPADES; suit <= Card.CLUBS; suit++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        cards[cardIndex++] = new Card(suit, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: In return this gave me an  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. It worked. Though I will read up a little bit more on this (fairly new to Java) and also try out the other things suggested by other people :) It was a fairly simple solution (as always) on which I spent way to many hours on.

Answer (score 1):

The array `CardDeck.cards` contains `null` elements because `i * suit` doesn't do what you expect when you use 1-based indexes (which you do in `Card.SPADES`)

Comment: OP is supposed not to change the Card class

Comment: Not quite: 0 will be null, followed by numbers not divisible by 1, 2, 3 and 4 between 14 and 52.

Comment: Fixed my answer. @BigMike: He needs to fix `CardDeck`, then.

Comment: @AaronDigulla ok, I do agree that real fix would be fixing the constant in Card class thou. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `getCard()` method of `CardDeck` class returns `null` instead of returning Card object. Check the `getCard()` method and print the Card obj before returning.